# turbo stream and comments tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, turbo

I have the following problem. I'm using turbo in a forum with a comment tree.

```
Commentary_1
    id="reply_to_commentary_1"
Commentary_2
    id="reply_to_commentary_2"
    Commentary _2_1
      id="reply_to_commentary_2_1"
```

When someone inserts a comment on for example Commentary _2_1, that comment is inserted into the id "reply_to_commentary_2_1" via turbo_stream for everyone on that page.

And the picture turns out

```
Commentary_1
    id="reply_to_commentary_1"
Commentary_2
    id="reply_to_commentary_2"
    Commentary _2_1
      id="reply_to_commentary_2_1"
        Commentary_2_1_1
           id="reply_to_commentary_2_1_1"
```

But if you do not reload the page, and someone clicks on the answer to Commentary_2_1_1 and answers there. The impression is that turbo_stream does not see the id "reply_to_commentary_2_1_1" and cannot insert it there

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The point of Turbo is to update the DOM without a page load. So I'm confused by "but if you do not reload the page".